# creating a package in tcl from a list of tcl/itcl sources

Tags: package, tcl, itcl

I want to make a tcl package , and I am writing In tcl and also in itcl.

Now , 
My first problem is that I have couple of sources files that are included one in the other , so I am adding the command `source` that should do the include between them. If I create a package with the command `package provide` is this will still work?

My second problem is that I don't really know how to create this package.
I added to my upper module script the command `package provide pack 1.0`, but I understood that auto_path should be also updated and mk_index file should with sources in it.
I searched on the internet and couldn't find good example for it.

By the way , I created all my classes and procedures under the global namespace in my sources files , is it ok? or should I wrap them inside a new namespace?

Comment: You can answer the question yourself and accept the answer. This is a better way since it means someone else can find your question and the answer with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I searched a little bit more about it and found those two absolutely wonderfull websites:
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl31.html
http://www.wjduquette.com/tcl/namespaces.html
it is explained there very good.